# Bidiagonalization and SVD of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

I can't find a single solid explanation of how to implement this -- whitepapers too detailed/confusing. Closest I came to an answer was this:

http://www.hep.ucl.ac.uk/~bino/libbpm/doc/pro/html/gsl__linalg_8c-source.html

see:

[1] gsl_linalg_bidiag_decomp

[2] gsl_linalg_SV_decomp (which calls [1])

Which perform it, but really, really obfusticate the process underneath.

Comment: I found the explanation in http://books.google.com/books?id=FtC9rHW7ORMC&pg=PA217 clear enough; which parts don't you understand?

Comment: If you want to learn the ins-and-outs of how to compute the SVD then a great way is write your own algorthim. If you want to actually use SVD as a means to an end then software packages will typically out-perform your implementation. 

Comment: Thanks guys I did implement my own with your help (esp. the google books link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Golub-Kahan Bidiagonalisation**

In this process householder reflectors are applied alternatively on the left and then the right. The $i^{\text{th}}$ left reflector introduces zeros below the diagonal in the $i^{\text{th}}$ column. The $i^{\text{th}}$ right reflector introduces zeros to the right of the first super-diagonal in the $i^{\text{th}}$ row.

In software packages I suspect they use a mixture of this Golub-Kahan bidiagonalisation and a process called Lawson-Hanson-Chan (LHC) bidiagonalisation depending on the size of the matrix.

**Computing the SVD**

The first phase of computing the SVD is bidiagonalising the matrix.  Then the SVD of the bidiagonal matrix is determined by a process very similar to the QR algorithm. This process is described in Golub and Kahn, ["Calculating the singular values and pseudo-inverse of a matrix"](http://www.amath.washington.edu/~narc/win08/papers/golub-kahan.pdf) (1960).
Since this paper there have been some alterations to provide better accuracy when the singular values are small, see Demmel and Kahan: "Accurate singular values of bidiagonal matrices" (1990)

Having been lectured by N. Trefethen on this very subject he briefly mentioned a divide-and-conquer type algorithm was now state-of-the-art though I don't know much about the details.

Comment: The divide and conquer approach is the straightforward application of the very same technique for the symmetric tridiagonal eigenproblem to a Golub-Kahan matrix, a matrix with zero diagonal and the alternating diagonal and off-diagonal entries of a bidiagonal matrix as off-diagonal entries. The key thing about a Golub-Kahan tridiagonal is that its positive eigenvalues correspond to the singular values of the associated bidiagonal.

Comment: In general, all the tricks for computing the eigenvalues of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix carry over to the bidiagonal SVD naturally by using them on the Golub-Kahan tridiagonal. As for bidiagonal SVD's state-of-the-art, the best one yet is "differential quotient difference", constructed by Parlett and Fernando from the old "quotient-difference" algorithm of Heinz Rutishauser.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks that is interesting. I'm going to get myself up to speed with all this now. (+1)